Conditionally importing a remote external CSS into a Vue 3 build with Vite
The Vue 3 application I am working on has a dependency on an external, remotely hosted stylesheet, but the source hostname to that sheet is also dependent on the environment.
To make things more complicated, the vue app needs to be hosted on a shared template that we can't add that css reference to directly, so we want to be able to compile it into the app.
I've used this library: CSS Injected by JS
to compile the app-specific styles into the compiled JS so that it's all self contained. This works with the styles defined in the templates, but I'm having a difficult time making this include the external stylesheet.
I added an import tag to the main app.vue component like this:
<style>
@import "https://dev.mysite.com/v/1.2.3/style.css"
</style>

and that works well enough; the stylesheet is loaded with the app and this would solve the problem!
Unfortunately, depending on where the app runs, that url for the css needs to change, like on stage it might be stage.mysite.com/v/1.0.1/style.css and on prod it might be just mysite.com/style.css...
I can't seem to figure out a way to make that @import action take a variable, or otherwise be conditional.
<style>
@import "WHAT GOES HERE TO MAKE IT VARIABLE?"
</style>

I can't bind nor put a variable in that style tag, so I'm not sure how I can achieve this...
I tried moving the import to code, like this:
onMounted(async () => {
const sheet = await import('https://dev.mysite.com/v/1.2.3/style.css', { with: { type: "css" }});
 
document.adoptedStyleSheets = [sheet.default];
})

But while this appears to work if I use a raw string, it fails if I pass that string from an environment variable instead (even though their contents are completely identical!) it fails:
onMounted(async () => {
    var sheetPath = String(import.meta.env.VITE_CSS_PATH);
const sheet = await import(sheetPath, { with: { type: "css" }});
 
document.adoptedStyleSheets = [sheet.default];
})

using a variable to import results in this error:

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but
the server responded with a MIME type of "text/css". Strict MIME type
checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Is there any way to do this?

You should probably use Env Variables

i just added more context in attempting to exactly this, but it doesn't work. a raw string does, but the env or a variable does not!

For example the following code works well -
.env file:
VITE_CSS=1.css

or:
VITE_CSS=2.css

Vue main.ts file:
const cssUrl = `https://imhvost.github.io/${import.meta.env.VITE_CSS}`;

const loadStyle = (url: string) => {
 const link = document.createElement('link');
 link.rel = 'stylesheet';
 link.href = url;
 document.head.appendChild(link);
};

loadStyle(cssUrl);


this was always my suggestion, but I got pushback in adding css to the head tag after the fact, due to the "flash" you see as it loads stuff after mounting... I figured that this is what Vue/Vite does anyway so I don't see the big deal. However, it would be nice if this could do what the js/css plugin does and integrate it so it doesn't need to be in the head. the @import in the style tag does exactly that, but I can't do it with a variable :(
